# AOP with Springboot, java.io.PrintStream

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-boot, spring-aop, printstream

built a simple springboot application with some aspects checking architecture and so on.

i try to catch every call to System.out.println() to give warning about usage
so that is what i've found so far:

System.out.println() uses PrintStream so that i've tried this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CleanCodeAspect {

    @Before("call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(String))")
    public void beforePrintlnCall() {
        System.out.println("About to make call to print Hello World");
   }

}
```

But with no success. 
The log says

```
The pointcutexpression call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(String)) contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'call'
```

A similar Aspect is working, but with execution instead of call:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class BooleanServiceMonitor {

    @Before("execution(* de.fhb..*Service.*(java.lang.Boolean))")
        public void logServiceAccess() {
            System.out.println("You used a method with only one boolean parameter. "
                    + "Refactor it into 2 methods with True, False at the end.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP, spring can only proxy spring based beans. Class implementing `PrintStream` aren't generally spring configured beans. Next to that Spring AOP only supports a subset of the AspectJ syntax (as the message indicates) it supports `execution` and the special `bean` pointcuts. If you want more you will have to use fullblown aspectj with load or compile time weaving.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Why don't you convert the comment into an answer? It is correct and deserves recognition. `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses [proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) to apply AOP, spring can only proxy spring based beans. Class implementing `PrintStream` aren't generally spring configured beans. Next to that Spring AOP only supports a [subset](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) of the [AspectJ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj) syntax (as the message indicates) it supports (amongst others) `execution` and the special `bean` pointcuts.

If you want to use more features (i.e. the `call` point cut) you will have to use [fullblown AspectJ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) with load or compile time weaving.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please take a look to my answer / next question above?

Comment: No. If you have another question open another question (I also flagged your current answer as such).